# File Selection From Remote Machine In Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, selection, paramiko

I am writing a program in python on Ubuntu. In that program I am struggling to select a file using the command `askopenfilename` on a remote network connected RaspberryPi.

Can anybody guide me on how to select a file from the remote machine using `askopenfilename` command or something similar?

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import paramiko

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()

    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('192.168.2.34', username='pi', password='raspberry')
    name1= askopenfilename(title = "Select File For Removal", filetypes = [("Video Files","*.h264")])
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l')
    for line in stdout:
        print '... ' + line.strip('\n')
    client.close()
```

Comment: Isn't it more feasible to mount the remote filesystem with `sshfs`, so that the remote files are accessible as local ones? You already seem to have the ssh access in place.

Comment: @RafaelLerm how do i do that

Comment: @IrfanGhaffar7 it depends on what OS do you use on your computer. For example, there's [a manual for Windows 8](http://igikorn.com/sshfs-windows-8/) on Google. Just google "how to install sshfs on (your OS)".

Comment: Now that you have the pointer to `sshfs`, you can try to do a search for it. Searching for "mount sshfs" gives you, along with many other good results, [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sshfs), which should be more than enough information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haha, hello again!

It's not possible to use a tkinter's file dialogs to list (or select) files on remote machine. You would need to mount the remote machine's drive using, for example, SSHFS (as mentioned in the question's comment), or use a custom tkinter dialog which displays the remote files list (that is in the `stdout` variable) and lets you choose the one.

You can write a dialog window yourself, here's a quick demo:

```
from Tkinter import *


def double_clicked(event):
    """ This function will be called when a user double-clicks on a list element.
        It will print the filename of the selected file. """
    file_id = event.widget.curselection()  # get an index of the selected element
    filename = event.widget.get(file_id[0])  # get the content of the first selected element
    print filename

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    files = ['file1.h264', 'file2.txt', 'file3.csv']

    # create a listbox
    listbox = Listbox(root)
    listbox.pack()

    # fill the listbox with the file list
    for file in files:
        listbox.insert(END, file)

    # make it so when you double-click on the list's element, the double_clicked function runs (see above)
    listbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", double_clicked)

    # run the tkinter window
    root.mainloop()
```

The easiest solution without a `tkinter` is - you could make the user type the filename using the [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function.

Kind of like that:

```
filename = raw_input('Enter filename to delete: ')
client.exec_command('rm {0}'.format(filename))
```

So the user would have to enter the filename that is to be deleted; then that filename gets passed directly to the `rm` command.

It's not really a safe approach - you should definitely escape the user's input. Imagine what if the user types `'-rf /*'` as a filename. Nothing good, even if you're not connected as a root.
But while you're learning and keeping the script to yourself I guess it's alright.

Comment: But actually in `askforfilename`, I just need to select it rather than typing the filename for removal purpose.
My filenames are very long and typical so that's y I wanna use it.